# Center a Div within a Div, CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm sure I'm missing something here... so I've dumbed down my question as much as I can so it makes sense. (I'm somewhat a novice at using CSS properly).

To clarify, I made a graphic that shows what I'm trying to accomplish, but I can't seem to get it right and I've been trying all day. I need a 100% wide header div, content in the middle, and a 100% wide footer div.   My footer div keeps going up behind my content area. CANT figure it out.

```
<div id="HEADER"></div>
<div id="CONTENT">
    <div id="contentwrap">
        <div id="top-left-photo"></div>
        <div id="top-right-date"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="FOOTER"></div>
```

I've also included a fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/b9kah2wx/

[image]

Thank you!!

Comment: You'll need to clear your floats to also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made some changes to your jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/b9kah2wx/2/

```
#HEADER {
    height:300;
    width: 100%;
}
#CONTENT {
    background-color: #C0F;
    height:auto;
    width: 100%;
}
#FOOTER {
    background-color: #C00;
    height:500px;
    width: 100%;
}
#contentwrap {
    width: 66%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:#0ff;
}
#top-left-photo {
    float:left;
    height: 180px;
    width: 40%;
    margin-right: 15px;
    background-color: #555555;
    font-family:"Dirty";
}
#top-right-date {
    float:left;
    height: 180px;
    width: 40%;
    margin-right: 0px;
    background-color: #555555;
}

.clearfix:after {
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     font-size: 0;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     height: 0;
     }
.clearfix { display: inline-block; }
/* start commented backslash hack \*/
* html .clearfix { height: 1%; }
.clearfix { display: block; }
/* close commented backslash hack */
```

You'll notice I changed the fixed width to percentages just so I could work with it in the jsfiddle but the basic idea is there.

You also need to clear your `float:`ed elements so the parent `div#contentwrap` height problem will get fixed. I've added this code for you.

and this is your HTML

```
<div id="HEADER"><h1>header</h1></div>
<div id="CONTENT">
    <div id="contentwrap">
        <div id="top-left-photo">photo</div>
        <div id="top-right-date"> date</div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="FOOTER"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this: Add the below code to your css file

```
* {
margin: 0 auto; /* Centers everything with a given with except when floated or altered with margin and position properties */
}
```

Note: It's important that you clear your floats as Paulie_D mentioned